# Spring + HibernateDaoSupport = не рекомендуются?

Tags: spring, dao, java, hibernate

Открыв несколько гайдов по связке Spring + Hibernate, обнаружил, что везде используется по-разному. Где используется реализация DAO примерно такая:

`public class StockDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements StockDao` - [взято отсюда (статья 2010-2012 гг.)](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/).

Ну а где-то почему-то HibernateDaoSupport  не наследуется, а реализуется интерфейс Dao и всё. А внутри обычная работа с сессиями hibernate, ручное закрытие и ручной коммит транзакций. [Вот как тут (2011 г.)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111102/).

Заинтересовавшись, нагуглил на [stackoverflow это (2011 г.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why), где сказано якобы про сильную привязку реализации DAO к Spring коду. Но я ведь работаю с интерфейсом, какая привязка? Ссылка старая, 2011 г. Так скажите, что используется сегодня - спринг 4 + хибернейт 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типичная практика это заинжектить фабрику сессий в Dao:

```
@Repository
public class MyDao {
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

А на сервис, который это дергает, соответственно повесить `@Transactional`.

Просто зачем тащить родословную своих Dao из чужих абстрактных классов (тем более наверняка захочется слепить свои абстрактные dao для базовых crud-операций)? Сейчас популярен подход делать обычные (pojo) классы и обвешивать их аннотациями.

Comment: Я в xml всё делал, есть что про спринг-аннотации гайд какой почитать? А то в официальной чёрт ногу сломает

Comment: Да вроде в актуальной доке все неплохо расписано. Гляньте на хабре по ключевым словам `sping аннотации`, были неплохие гайды:

 - http://habrahabr.ru/post/112488/
 - http://geektimes.ru/post/48439/
 - http://habrahabr.ru/post/48606/